# Natural Join in Relational Algebra - Database Theory

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra, natural-join, database-theory

Could I have still came up with the correct answer if I deleted the yellow part? Is it even neccesary?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Hi. Please read hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Say what reference you are following and/or quote the definitions & processes you are following. Explain your reasoning & where & why you are stuck. Why would the yellow not matter? PS The natural join symbol is a "bow tie".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is no homework:

I guess `|X|` is natural join and `#` denotes the primary key attributes.

The highlighted projection on `S#` is not necessary with respect to 
correctness of the query result (effectiveness).

However, it may increase efficiency: Project as early as possible to 
remove duplicates *before* the join. This avoids the unnecessary effort 
of first producing duplicate natjoined tuples which the projection on 
`sname` then has to remove.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicates"? I guess not projecting would result in a few extra columns like "P#" and "QUANTITY". Am i right?

Comment: I meant duplicate tuples. In theory relational algebra is a set theoretic concept where such thing as "duplicate" does not exist. But in practice, when you have to implement a RDBMS, duplicates occur and to be consistent with the theory they must be somehow dealt with.

Comment: I just checked the definition of projection and found out it only takes unique values.

What I realized is that there might be duplicate shipments made by the same supplier with same product but different quantity(or same but done in some other time and put in database causing a duplicate) and this projection operation removes those duplicates and only takes uniques.

Thank you very much, you have made me clear myself.

Comment: Every operator of relational algebra  removes duplicates.

Comment: @J.Doe Relational operators do not "remove duplicates", they do not produce "duplicates". If you describe their results by converting relations to non-relations, eg bags or lists, and later back to relations, then that description might involve "removing duplicates".

Comment: @J.Doe Under the usual interpretation, 'S supplies P and has Q in stock', each < S, P > subrow value can only appear in one row. And it is unlikely to instead state something on a per-shipment basis because it cannot record 2 shipments with the same Q, only that some shipment has had a given Q. But these uniqueness issues don't matter to the query, because constraints are not needed to query; regardless of constraints, your queries return names of Ss associated with p3 for some Q.

Answer (score 2):

In order to know whether or not you can leave it out, you have to look at what the predicates are that correspond to the expression and its sub-expressions.

For example, that innermost restrict says (I presume because the example is familiar) "Supplier S# supplies part P# in quantity QUANTITY AND P# = 3". Or shorter "Supplier S# supplies part 3 in quantity QUANTITY".

The projection on S# of that then says "there exists some quantity q such that supplier S# supplies part 3 in that quantity".

The JOIN with S of that then says "Supplier S# is named SNAME, [familiar part snipped] AND there exists some quantity q such that supplier S# supplies part 3 in that quantity".  Or shorter "Supplier S# is named SNAME, [familiar part snipped] AND supplies part 3 in some quantity".

The projection on SNAME of that then says "there exists some S#, CITY, STATUS such that Supplier S# is named SNAME, [familiar part snipped] AND supplies part 3 in some quantity".

You do the same for the case when the "inner projection" is left out and then try to prove that the predicate obtained must be equivalent to this one.  If you can, you know including that projection is unnecessary.  [And if you can't you must try harder :-) ]

Comment: "Supplier S# supplies part 3 in quantity QUANTITY" No because P# should be free. PS It's not clear what you mean by "that [expression] says". You seem to mean something like "that [expression] has a corresponding predicate that says". But you don't explain "correspond to" or what that has to do with query results or querying. (Like, a query expression's value is the set of tuples that make its corresponding predicate into a true proposition.) Or what you mean by predicate here. So from the point of view of a reader that doesn't know all these terms, this is not very clear.